# Datetime not formatting properly as d:hh:mm

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, date-arithmetic

I have a Google spreadsheet where I'm finding the amount of time between two datetime values. The calculation seems to be working properly, because when I output the value as just a number, it looks correct. However, when I try to format it as d:hh:mm, for any values where the two dates are on the same day, it is showing me 30 days instead of 0. Some sample data:

```
Datetime        | Diff as # | Diff as d:hh:mm  
8/13/2016 20:24 |           |
8/27/2016 00:09 | 13.15625  | 13:03:45         (this line is correct)
8/27/2016 04:43 | 0.190278  | 30:04:34         (this is incorrect, should be 0 days, not 30)
```

When I try the same thing in Excel, it works as expected. (instead of 30:04:34, I get 00:04:34) So I think it's some difference between the two that I'm not familiar with. Can someone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, Google sheets don't have the feature to show the duration in days (via custom format), you can only have it in hours and/or minutes and/or seconds..

Screenshot:
[image]

Still there is a workaround to get the desired format, try the following formula in cell C3:

```
=(datevalue(A3)-datevalue(A2))&text(time(0,0,(A3-A2)*24*60*60),":HH:mm")
```

Screenshot:
[image]

EDIT (after viewing the comment):

Try the following formula:

```
=rounddown(A3-A2)&" days "&text(time(0,0,(A3-A2)*24*60*60),"HH:mm")
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you. One minor problem, if the second value is on a later date, the calculation is adding an extra day. [See highlighted cells here](http://imgur.com/rpDEA6T) Is there a way to fix that? Also, would it be possible to format this as "0 days 04:34" for readability?

Comment: Try this: =rounddown(A3-A2)&" days "&text(time(0,0,(A3-A2)*24*60*60),"HH:mm")

Comment: Looks like that did it. Thanks!